# Browser Hang Issue - While working on the Large Angular Material Trees with 7000 Nodes

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, treeview

[Preview of the Page which starts misbehaving in case of large data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gB8F.png)

**Code For the Right Tree**   Tree Have the Drag and Drop functionality from left to right (Logical Implementation is same as CDK Drag and Drop Tree Implemented in Angular Material Tree).
Please Look into the Code and any suggestions for improvement related to performance in this tree would be highly appreciated.

```
    <div class="divright" [style.width]="!leftTreeFlag ? '96%' : '48%'">
      <mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSourceRightTree" [treeControl]="treeControlRightTree" cdkDropList
        (cdkDropListDropped)="dropRightTree($event)">


        <mat-tree-node style="border:2px solid #dfdfdf" matTreeNodePadding
          *matTreeNodeDef="let rightNode; when: hasNoContent">
          <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput #itemValue1 placeholder="New item...">
          </mat-form-field>
          <button mat-button (click)="saveRightNode(rightNode, itemValue1.value)">Save</button>
          <i style="padding-top: 10px;text-align:right;float:right;font-size:20px;cursor:pointer;" width="100"
            class="material-icons" (click)="deleteNodeFromRightTree(rightNode)">remove_circle_outline</i>
        </mat-tree-node>

        <mat-tree-node style="border:2px solid #dfdfdf" *matTreeNodeDef="let rightNode; when : isActiveAndNoChild"
          matTreeNodePadding cdkDrag [cdkDragData]="rightNode" (mouseenter)="dragRightTreeHover(rightNode)"
          (mouseleave)="rightDragHoverEnd()" (cdkDragStarted)="rightDragStart(rightNode)"
          (cdkDragReleased)="rightDragEnd()">

          <button mat-icon-button disabled> </button>
          <!-- <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle
                            [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + rightNode.filename">
                            <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
                                {{treeControlRightTree.isExpanded(rightNode) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
                            </mat-icon>
                        </button> -->

          {{rightNode.rackName}}


          <span>
            <i *ngIf="rightNode.level !== 0 && rightNode.permission != 0" style=" padding-top:
                                10px;text-align:right;float:right;font-size:20px;cursor:pointer;" width="100"
              class="material-icons" (click)="deleteNodeFromRightTree(rightNode)">remove_circle_outline</i>
            <i *ngIf="rightNode.permission != 0"
              style="padding-top: 10px;text-align: right;font-size:20px;float:right;cursor:pointer;"
              class="material-icons" (click)="addNewRightItem(rightNode)"> add</i>
            <i style="padding-top: 10px;text-align: right;float:right;font-size:20px;cursor:pointer;"
              *ngIf="rightNode.level !== 0 && rightNode.permission != 0" class=" material-icons"
              (click)="openSettingDialogue(rightNode)">settings</i>
          </span>
          <div style="padding: 3px; width: 20%;" [style.background-color]="rightNode.color"> </div>
          <!-- <button style="text-align:right;float:right;font-size:20px" mat-icon-button
                            (click)="addNewRightItem(rightNode)">
                            <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
                        </button> -->
        </mat-tree-node>



        <mat-tree-node style="border:2px solid #dfdfdf" *matTreeNodeDef="let rightNode" matTreeNodePadding>
        </mat-tree-node>

        <mat-tree-node style="border:2px solid #dfdfdf" *matTreeNodeDef="let rightNode; when: isActiveAndHasChild "
          matTreeNodePadding cdkDrag [cdkDragData]="rightNode" (mouseenter)="dragRightTreeHover(rightNode)"
          (mouseleave)="rightDragHoverEnd()" (cdkDragStarted)="rightDragStart(rightNode)"
          (cdkDragReleased)="rightDragEnd()">

          <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + rightNode.filename">
            <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
              {{treeControlRightTree.isExpanded(rightNode) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
            </mat-icon>
          </button>
          {{rightNode.rackName}}
          <span>
            <i *ngIf="rightNode.level !== 0 && rightNode.permission != 0" style=" padding-top:
                                10px;text-align:right;float:right;font-size:20px;cursor:pointer;" width="100"
              class="material-icons" (click)="deleteNodeFromRightTree(rightNode)">remove_circle_outline</i>
            <i *ngIf="rightNode.permission != 0"
              style="padding-top: 10px;text-align: right;float:right;font-size:20px;cursor:pointer;"
              class="material-icons" (click)="addNewRightItem(rightNode)"> add</i>
            <i style="padding-top: 10px;text-align: right;font-size:20px;float:right;cursor:pointer;"
              *ngIf="rightNode.level !== 0 && rightNode.permission != 0" class="material-icons"
              (click)="openSettingDialogue(rightNode)">settings</i>
            <i style="padding-top: 10px;float:right;font-size:20px;cursor:pointer;" *ngIf="rightNode.level === 0"
              class="material-icons" (click)="openDialog()">settings</i>
          </span>
          <div style="padding: 3px; width: 20%;" [style.background-color]="rightNode.color"> </div>
          <!-- <button style="text-align:right;float:right;font-size:20px" mat-icon-button
                            (click)="addNewRightItem(rightNode)">
                            <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
                        </button> -->

        </mat-tree-node>
      </mat-tree>
    </div>
```